# Automated format in a nested enumerate environment

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, tufte

I have to do a small document, in which I intend to use `Tufte-handout` rather than `article` or `Scrartcl` classes and compile it with `XeLaTeX` with a typography I intend to use.

However I have a difficulty with the format, I have to use the `enumerate` environment nested in three levels with the following characteristics:

1. The item marker appears in color (red), for this I think I can load
   the `xcolor` package before `\documentclass` to
   `\PassOptionToPackage` or something like that. But I don't know how
   to define it automatically for each item.
2. The method of numbering the list, I need to appear as:

   1

   1.1

   1.1.1

and not:

```
1.
(a)
i.
```

as default.

Finally I think this is the most difficult (or I don't know how to achieve it) and it's the format of each level of nesting:

- 1st level item: in roman letter (default value)
- 2nd level item: in small caps (and sometimes in small italic caps).
  The font I chose can achieve it without problems.
- 3rd level item: in italics but without using `\emph{}` I've already
  used and I don't think it's the best choice.

Any idea how to do this? I can do it manually but as it is a fairly long list because it would prefer to automate in the preamble.

---

### Update

Well, after the suggestion of use enumitem I triead with good results. The suggestion is in the code below as a MWE, it is:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Warnock Pro}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii.}        
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}           
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi . \theenumii.} 
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}        
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{
           \theenumi . \theenumii . \theenumiii.}  
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\textcolor{red}{1}] This is a first level item
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textsc{This is a second level item}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{This is a third level item}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

It works, now I need to add color to the label of the first level, and automate the format of the content as I described before.

Comment: I think package `enumitem` comes to help here. But do you really want the same thing once with a period (1.1) and a level higher up with out a period (1)?

Comment: Well, the period is a kind of marker of level. I don't need a final period in any level, so in this case will be: 1 and later 1.1 and the deepest level 1.1.1

Comment: I don't understand what the level of nesting is. That is not the same as the levels of the enumerate environment, which are nested. So what is that for?

Comment: Are we talking about the number format or the format of contents?

Comment: @cfr I use three levels of enumeration with the enumerate environment. Is a large list with about 100 items. Isn't that nested?

Comment: @HarishKumar Both formats.

Comment: Yes. But you seem to have 2 lots of nesting. What's the roman - small caps - italic sequence for? I understand about the arabic - arabic dotted - arabic dotted dotted on its own. That's a simple 3 level enumerate. But then you say you want something completely different for those levels.

Comment: That code doesn't make use of `enumitem` at all, by the way. You might as well not load it if you do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumitem` offers specialised ways to customise lists which was why it was recommended in this case. If you look at the documentation, you'll appreciate that the point is to abstract away from the need to use the lower level LaTeX list configuration macros.

The following example shows one way. I very much doubt I have Warnock Pro so I created a MWE *sans* the fancy font stuff. Hence, this example uses the default Computer Modern.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=.\arabic*, after=\normalfont}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*, font=\normalfont\color{red}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{before=\normalfont\scshape}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{font=\normalfont\upshape, before=\normalfont\itshape}
\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item This is a first level item
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item This is a second level item
     \begin{enumerate}
       \item This is a third level item
     \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
 abc
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy list]

Comment: Great!!! That's exactly what I need. Very nice example. Bow I need to automate also the format of each item according to its level within.

Comment: @Aradnix I have no idea what you mean. This formats the content of each item according to level as specified in your question. I'm not sure what the further formatting you want consists of.

Comment: Yes, you're right sorry I was asleep and didn't read well the code, it's perfect, really `enumitem` makes it extremely easy. Thanks.

Comment: @Aradnix Yes. `enumitem` is great!

Comment: How could I in the 3rd level let in italics only the contents of the item but not the label?

Comment: @Aradnix You could try adding `\upshape` to the `font=` for that level, which affects only the label.

Comment: If I try `\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\upshape, before=\scshape}` I get something weird: the number disepears, and if I try with `\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\upshape, before=\scshape}` appears as _1_ instead _1.1.1_

Comment: @Aradnix `font=` ***not*** `label=`.

Comment: Now I have a strange behaviour, all works fine but the letter in the 3rd level appears in small slanted capitals instead of italics. I tried to create a new MWE for update the question but it works fine as it should do always. I have hundreds of items and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Aradnix Please try it now.

Comment: I did it three times, and there are no changes.

Comment: @Aradnix In that case, I don't know without an MWE. The changes I made to my answer fix the problem which I guessed might be causing issues, but if the changes don't solve the problem for you, then it must be a different problem. Without an example, it is hard to say more than that.

Comment: Yes, I know, maybe is something related with the `tufte-latex` class.